# Font rendering with DirectX HLSL

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl, direct3d, freetype

I have Direct3D monochrome font textures that I genrated using the FreeType library I can rendering fine but I'm now trying to color them.

I first explored trying todo this using fixed fuctions as I have no HLSL experence, but seems Direct3D has now removed all that stuff.

I tried to use the following code as a test but found it filled the whole texture with the test color so rather than a font I got a filled rectangle.

Unable to find much in the DirectX documentation, how can this be done?

```cpp
const char* g_strTTFPixelShaderProgram = 
"float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR"
"{"
"    float4 originalColor; "
"    originalColor = tex2D( InputTexture , uv.xy); "
"    if(originalColor.r<TargetColor.r + Tolerance && originalColor.r>TargetColor.r - Tolerance"
"      &&originalColor.g<TargetColor.g + Tolerance&&originalColor.g>TargetColor.g - Tolerance"
"      &&originalColor.b<TargetColor.b + Tolerance&&originalColor.b>TargetColor.b - Tolerance)"
"    {"
"       float4 ARGB;     "                        
"       ARGB.a = 1.0;    "                       
"       ARGB.r = 0;      "                      
"       ARGB.g = 128;    "                     
"       ARGB.b = 0;      "      
"              originalColor.rgb = ARGB;"
"    }"
"    return float4(originalColor.rgb, originalColor.a); "
"}"
;
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but i would suggest to use raw string literal for shader code to avoid all those extra double quotes.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) as it includes a bunch of ready-made HLSL shaders. Also see [this legacy Effects sample](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/main/FixedFuncEMUFX11).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a monochrome font texture (in assumption that glyphs are white - ones in all channels, and background's transparent black - zeroes in all channels), you need to multiple a texel fetched from this texture to the desired color.

```
`const char* g_strTTFPixelShaderProgram = 
"float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR"
"{"
"    float4 originalColor = tex2D( InputTexture , uv.xy);"
"    float3 tintColor = float3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);"
"    return float4(originalColor.rgb * tintColor, originalColor.a);"
"}"
;`
```